# How to get "all" in a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the database schema

```
Parts 
  (pid:integer, pname:string, year:integer, price:integer)

Suppliers 
  (sid:integer, sname: string, state:string, zipcode:string)

Orders 
  (pid:integer, sid:integer, quantity:integer)
```

Find the names of parts that were supplied from all states.

Find the zipcode of suppliers that supply all parts. List each zipcode once.

I am a little confused as to how to approach the questions where it asks for "all". I do not know how to write a query that can take "all" of something.

We are learning about division and aggregates.

Comment: Just JOIN tables. If no WHERE criteria given - it will return all rows

Comment: post samples of data and expected result please

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes English usage can be subtle and "all" is used as a synonym for "any". In this case that's not true so most of the answers are missing the point of your question. One way to make sure something is true for two sets with multiple rows in each is to count them up and then compare the totals. That's the reason for all the count() expressions in the two queries.

Here's one possibility for the zipcode question:

```
select zipcode
from Suppliers
where
    (select count(pid) from Parts) =
    (select count(distinct pid) from Orders where sid = Suppliers.sid)
```

Here's the second one:

```
select name
from Parts
where pid in (
    select Orders.pid,
    from Suppliers inner join Orders on Orders.sid = Suppliers.sid
    group by Orders.pid
    having
        count(distinct Suppliers.state) =
        (select count(distinct state) from Suppliers)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**To get all names using mysql**
```

select p.pname from parts p join orders o on p.pid=o.pid join Suppliers s on           o.sid= s.sid where s.state is not null;

```
**To get distinct names**
```

select distinct p.pname from parts p join orders o on p.pid=o.pid 
   join Suppliers s on o.sid= s.sid where s.state is not null;

or u can use 'in ' keyword..
   like 
   select p.pname from parts p join orders o on p.pid=o.pid join Suppliers s on 
   o.sid= s.sid where s.state in (select distinct state from Suppliers);

Answer (score 0):

"All States" means DON'T filter on state.  Whereas if they said "for Ohio" you would add a WHERE clause such as:

```
WHERE ZipCode in (SELECT Zip FROM Zips WHERE State = 'OH')
```

That subquery gets your state from an assumed zips table, replace with however you translate zips to states.  But in your case, you wouldn't need to anyways.

Answer (score 0):

`Select pname from Parts where pid IN (Select pid from Orders where Suppliers.sid = Orders.sid)`

Similarly for the 2nd one. "All" means, you should not add where clause on that field.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

-- select the names of parts that were supplied from all states --

```
select t.pid, max(pname) from
(
    -- states, where pname was supplied from --
    select distinct p.pid, p.pname, s.state
    from 
    Parts p 
    join
    Orders o on o.pid = p.pid
    join 
    Suppliers s on s.sid = o.sid
) t
group by t.pid
-- part was supplied from all state if --
having count(t.state) = 
    (
        -- total number of states
        select count(distinct state) from Suppliers
    )
```

-- select the zipcode of suppliers that supply all parts --

```
select max(s.zipcode)
from 
Suppliers s
join Order o
on o.sid = s.sid
group by s.sid
having count(distinct o.pid) = (select count(distinct pid) from Parts)
```